# How to split a large array into smaller array based upon given index values,

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array e.g. `aa=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`

I have another array which holds the indexes values based upon which large array need to be chunked. e.g. `cc=[10,16]`

I want that array **aa** to be chunked into new arrays

**dd[]** = [from 0 to cc[0]index]

**ee[]** = [from cc[0]index to cc[next value]index]

EXAMPLE

```
dd[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ee[] = [11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

and so on until `cc[]` has indexes

I could not figure out the logic, if anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the parts.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    indices = [10, 16],
    result = indices.map(function (a, i, aa) {
        return array.slice(aa[i - 1] || 0, a);
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: with so many correct answers, its difficult to select one. Wish I can mark all.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the new and simple array.slice:

```js
    var array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
    for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);
        console.info(temparray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you don't wanna use build in methods.

```js
function createChunks(aa, cc) {
    var temp = [], chunks = [];
    for(var i=0, j=0, k=0; i<aa.length; i++) {
        if(aa[i] == cc[j]) {
            temp[k] = aa[i];
            chunks.push(temp);
            temp = []; k=0; j++;
        }
        else
            temp[k++] = aa[i];
    }
    return chunks;
}


var aa=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], cc=[10, 16];

var chunks = createChunks(aa, cc);
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks));
```